# Getting initial data in vuejs application

Tags: vue.js, vuex

Right now, I getting initial data in my `app.vue` file in the `beforeCreated` hook.

```
 beforeCreate () {
    store.dispatch('getConfig')
 }
```

And the child components needs the data in the mounted hook data.

But the data is not always available.

What is the best way to retrieve initial data that is used in child components?

Comment: What do you need to do in `mounted` that you can't do in `beforeCreate`? The reactivity in Vue should make this pretty much a non-issue.

Comment: Put the child components in a `v-if` so that they don't render until the data is available?

Comment: is `getConfig` async? on what component do you use the config? it would help if you can post the relevant parts of your store and components

Comment: It is not aync, it is used globally